# HTML form action and mailerlite email submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've created a webform in mailerlite, Then I tried to integrate it in a section in homepage of my website, So I created an html form as this :

```
<form class="ml-block-form" action="//app.mailerlite.com/webforms/submit/myownID" data-code="myownID" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <div class="form-group ml-field-email ml-validate-required ml-validate-email">
        <input class="newsletter-email" type="email" name="fields[email]" placeholder="Email*"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="ml-submit" value="1" />
    <p>
        <input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Get Updates!"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

And also, I've used these javascript codes :

```
    <!-- MailerLite Universal -->
<script>
    (function(m,a,i,l,e,r){m['MailerLiteObject']=e;function f() {
        var c={a:arguments,q:[]};var r=this.push(c);return "number"!=typeof r?r:f.bind(c.q);}
        f.q=f.q||[];m[e]=m[e]||f.bind(f.q);m[e].q=m[e].q||f.q;r=a.createElement(i);
        var _=a.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];r.async=1;r.src=l+'?'+(~~(new Date().getTime()/10000000));
        _.parentNode.insertBefore(r,_);})(window, document, 'script', 'http://static.mailerlite.com/js/universal.js', 'ml');

        var ml_account = ml('accounts', 'MyAccountID', 'MyWebformID', 'load');
</script>
<!-- End MailerLite Universal -->
```

and :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static1.mailerlite.com/js/w/webforms.js?v15"></script>
```

Now the problem is that when **someone enters his email** and **clicks on submit** button, **his email** will be **saved in mailerlite subscribers** database **successfully**, **but a new tab opens** and the mentioned webform **comes up again**.
I don't want it to open a new tab, I just want the **submit button to be converted** to a rotating icon, then **after a few seconds** it's text be converted to something like "**You've successfully subscribed**".
How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `target="_blank"` to prevent the new window.

Comment: Did you try removing the `target="_blank"` in your `<form>` tag?

Comment: removing `target="_blank"` will result in opening that webform in the current page, I want to stay in the current webpage when subscribing, And just submit button to be converted to something else when I successfully subscribe...

Comment: If mailerlite allow it (they seem to) the method for doing that is to use JavaScript to submit the form via Ajax.

Comment: @AlexK.Would you please send this as a complete answer?